# How to increase font size of the entire application (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, .net-2.0, font-size

I have a tool, and now  I want the font of the entire application to be incremented by some margin. Is there anyway to do that in one neat step? It should be painstaking to go to each and every control and set the font size.

Comment: Is this something you need to do at run-time or design-time?

Comment: @LarsTech be it any. I prefer design time. There is no much tweaking after that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Controls inherit the font from their parent by default, so you only need to change the font on the forms.